# Is there a way to get Group Guests using the calendar service in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am writing a tool in Google Sheets to analyze my work calendar and I just noticed that if I invite a "Group" (of 23 people) it only shows up as a single guest in the calendar data. Is there a way to get access to the e-mails of the people in the group?

From my research I know there is a Groups service but I'm not sure how to even recognize that it's a group. It looks like a normal e-mail address in the calendar: "management_team@gmail.com". (I could search for that specific group name, but I'm looking for a universal solution, so I can share this tool with others.)

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### To verify either an email is a group and to retrieve its members you need to use the Admin SDK method [Groups:get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/get)

But in order to use the Admin SDK you need to be a domain admin.

Answer (score 0):

Each person who uses my tool will need their own copy and they will have to enter their calendar e-mail address. (The first time they run the tool there's a rather scary permissions message, but I will only be sharing this with some office mates so that should be okay.)

When my program runs I'll use this command:

```
  var groups = GroupsApp.getGroups();
```

... to get a list of all the groups to which that person belongs. (I'll also have arrays for the members of each group.) Then I'll just compare the group names against the meeting guest names. If there's a match I can pretty easily retrieve the whole list.